Azure Service Bus: AbandonMessageAsync Not Increasing Delivery Count and Generating Excessive Log Entries
My team is using Azure Functions to process messages from an Azure Service Bus queue. They are to trigger when a message is added to the respected queue.
We're noticing that the delivery count of the message is not increasing as expected. This has resulted in a massive influx of log entries—around 8 million AppException entries in just 2.5 days, which is extremely costly and unexpected.
This was caused by just 1 message in the Queue (thankfully we just had 1 message...)
I suspect that the delivery count isn't incrementing properly, causing messages to be retried excessively without ever reaching the max delivery count and being dead-lettered. This could also mean that AbandonMessageAsync is not functioning as expected in some scenarios.
Here are the details of the queue configuration:
Lock Duration: 1 minute
Max Delivery Count: 10
Message Time to Live: 3 days
The function is intended to handle PDF generation requests and uses ServiceBusTrigger to receive messages. Below is a simplified version of the function code:
[Function(nameof(PDFGenFunction))]
public async Task Run(
[ServiceBusTrigger(SourceQueue, Connection = ConnectionStringKey)]
ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
{
    try
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Message ID: {message.MessageId}");
        _logger.LogInformation($"PdfGenerationRequest - Received message: {message.Body.ToString()}");
        _logger.LogInformation($"Message Content-Type: {message.ContentType}");

        var outputJSON = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OutputJSON>(message.Body.ToString());
        if (outputJSON != null)
        {
            var result = await SendPdfGenerationRequest(message.Body.ToString());
            if(result.Status == PdfResponseStatus.Queued)
            {
                await SendMessageToPdfCompletionQueue(result);
                await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogError($"PdfGenerationRequest - request failed: {result.Urn}, application string: {message.Body.ToString()}");
                await messageActions.AbandonMessageAsync(message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogError($"PdfGenerationRequest - Invalid JSON string data, application string: {message.Body.ToString()}");
            await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Error processing application submission: {messageBody}", message.Body.ToString());

        await messageActions.AbandonMessageAsync(message);
    }
}

hosts.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "visibilityTimeout": "00:03:00",
      "maxDequeueCount": 5
    }
  }
}

I've looked at our settings and I don't see anything wrong with the implementation, the only thing I could think of is an API call took longer than 1 minute, but then that doesn't add up as we had over 8 million records and there's not that many minutes in the weekend.
I'm looking for some help on how to drill into this so we can prevent this from occurring in the future.


After heading back to the Documents the following line was the culprit:
await messageActions.AbandonMessageAsync(message);

This code removes the lock on the message instantly allowing it to be triggered again. What the code should have done is throw;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.servicebus.servicebusmessageactions.abandonmessageasync?view=azure-dotnet

If you throw, the message is still going to be reprocessed 10 times, with a minute in between the attempts, causing the same amount of log entries. With throwing, you just slowed down the speed of the logs, not the amount.
